# How Can i List all rds instances in aws in all regions using python boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, list, boto3, amazon-rds

I don't know how to get all rds instances of all regions in aws with python . Please help .

Comment: Did you try anything at all? Any code that you wrote and it does not work?

Comment: Yes , it is solved now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call [`describe_db_instances()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_db_instances):

> Returns information about provisioned RDS instances.

Amazon RDS is a regional service. To list instances from multiple regions, you would need to loop through a list of regions and then:

- Create a boto3 client for that region
- Call `describe_db_instances()`

For example:

```py
import boto3

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

# Retrieves all regions/endpoints that work with EC2
regions = ec2_client.describe_regions()

# Loop through each region
for region in regions['Regions']:

    # Create an RDS client for the region
    rds_client = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region['RegionName'])

    # List RDS instances
    response = rds_client.describe_db_instances()
    for db in response['DBInstances']:
        print(db['DBInstanceIdentifier'])
```

Comment: How to do that on organization level? I need it for RDS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71471571/python-boto3-get-all-rds-instance-list-of-an-organization